# How to check in a shell script if an executable is running or not?

Tags: shell, shell-script

I have put an executable in a shell script file abc.sh. Now, I want to add *one* line in this abc.sh, to know whether it is running before my script starts or not *and* if yes, the *kill* that executable.

Comment: I think you need to clarify the last part, when you say "kill that executable" do you mean the instance of the executable that it finds or the one that makes the match?

Comment: kill `pidof nameofprogram`

Comment: What are you [*really*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) trying to do? Keep a process running indefinitely? Check for some state every N seconds? Something else?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `pgrep` to find executables with given process name:

```
$ pgrep firefox
3212
$ pgrep firef
3212
```

Use `-l` option to print names in second column:

```
$ pgrep -l firefox
3212 firefox
```

Use `-x` option to  match processes whose name exactly match the pattern.

```
$ pgrep -x firefox
3212
$ pgrep -x firef
$
```

When you have PID of executable returned, you can kill it. You also can do it in single step using `pkill` command if you are not interested in value of PID:

```
$ pkill -x firefox
```

It will kill process with given name. If there is no such a process, nothing will happen except setting $? variable to 1.

Comment: When running with `set -e` (which is good practice for shell scripts) a failed command will exit the shell, so you may need a `|| true` in that case.

Answer (score 6):

```
# killall executable_name
```

or

```
# pkill executable_name
```

will do it, but it's a [bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#How_do_I_kill_a_process_by_name.3F__I_need_to_get_the_PID_out_of_ps_aux_.7C_grep_....). That article explains very well why (essentially, program names are entirely arbitrary, and you could easily kill the wrong process), and how to do it properly (restructure the program so you don't have to kill by name).